# How to load Custom Template file in Wordpress running on WAMP Server?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, bitnami

I have used custom template file for invoices in woocommerce orders but the invoice pdf containing custom template does not load rather on clicking the button the page redirects to the bitnami home page and does not load the custom template. How can I fix this issue in localhost?

Answer (score 0):

To change the invoice content in woocommerce you can create the same file and put in woocommerce folder in current theme File path should be  same as like that exist in woocommerce plugin folder for invoice template .

Otherwise you can also use the invoice hooks to generate the custom invoice

Thanks